# Mvc - System.Web.Caching - Absolute Expiration & UpdateCallback - Timeout is always 20 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

### Question

Why doesn't the [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) `onUpdateCallback` respect the `absolutionExpiration` time?

### Context

I'm experimenting with creating a cache strategy that will automatically refresh itself after a given interval.  However, I want the cache to refresh on the background thread instead of evicting and then waiting for a new user request to force a cache refresh.  I've elected to use the `onUpdateCallback` to repopulate the cache once the absolute expiration has been reached.

### Code

I've created a sample Controller to illustrate this:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private const string CacheKey = "Test";

    //Simple function to get current time
    private readonly Func<string> GetTime = 
        () => DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss fff");

    //Cache for 5 seconds
    private readonly TimeSpan _cacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

    private static bool _cacheWarmed = false;

    private void WarmCache()
    {
        if (_cacheWarmed)
            return;

        _cacheWarmed = true;

        //Cache current time
        HttpContext.Cache
            .Insert(
                key: CacheKey,
                value: GetTime(),
                dependencies: null,
                absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.Add(_cacheDuration),
                slidingExpiration: Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                //On cache eviction - cache current time (ie eviction time)
                onUpdateCallback:
                      (string s,
                        CacheItemUpdateReason reason,
                        out object cachedItem,
                        out CacheDependency dependency,
                        out DateTime expiration,
                        out TimeSpan slidingExpiration) =>
                      {
                          expiration = DateTime.Now.Add(_cacheDuration);
                          cachedItem = GetTime();
                          dependency = null;
                          slidingExpiration = Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
                      }); 
    }

    public ActionResult GetCachedTime()
    {
        WarmCache();

        return new ContentResult 
        {  
             Content =  (string)HttpContext.Cache.Get(CacheKey) 
        }; 
    }
}
```

And a simple Html with some javascript to call the method over and over again and output the result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myFunc = function()
        {
            var startTime = new Date().getTime();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/example/GetCachedTime"
            }).done(function(data) {

                var currentTime = new Date();

                var msg =
                    currentTime.toLocaleTimeString() +
                    ": [" +
                    data +
                        "] - Executed in " +
                        (currentTime.getTime() - startTime) +
                        " ms <br/>";

                $("#container").append(msg);

                console.log(msg);
            });
        };

        var intervalHandle = setInterval(myFunc, 2000);

        myFunc();
    });
</script>
```

### Results

Truncated for brevity:

```
 3:45:52 PM: [15:45:40 387] - Executed in 30 ms 
 3:45:55 PM: [15:45:40 387] - Executed in 4 ms 
 3:45:57 PM: [15:45:40 387] - Executed in 4 ms 
 3:45:59 PM: [15:45:40 387] - Executed in 4 ms 
 3:46:01 PM: [15:46:00 399] - Executed in 4 ms 
 3:46:03 PM: [15:46:00 399] - Executed in 4 ms 
         (duplicates removed - :04 - :18)
 3:46:19 PM: [15:46:00 399] - Executed in 3 ms 
 3:46:21 PM: [15:46:20 406] - Executed in 4 ms 
 3:46:23 PM: [15:46:20 406] - Executed in 3 ms 
         (duplicates removed - :24 - :38)
 3:46:39 PM: [15:46:20 406] - Executed in 3 ms 
 3:46:41 PM: [15:46:40 418] - Executed in 3 ms 
 3:46:43 PM: [15:46:40 418] - Executed in 3 ms 
         (duplicates removed - :44 - :58)
 3:46:59 PM: [15:46:40 418] - Executed in 3 ms 
 3:47:01 PM: [15:47:00 419] - Executed in 3 ms 
 3:47:03 PM: [15:47:00 419] - Executed in 3 ms
```

**The method is cached for `20` seconds, even though I set the timeout for `5`!**

I've experimenting with changing the cache duration:

- `_cacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)` - No change
- `_cacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)` - No change
- `_cacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)` - No change
- `_cacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 25)` - Cached for 40 seconds

### Question Reprise

So what's going on here?  Why is cache duration not respected?  Or did I not setup the Cache correctly?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an internal timer in the ASP.NET cache that checks expiration every 20 seconds. 5 seconds is too short of a time period without tweaking the cache polling period, which some users have done.